# ghost/unghost fields according to user input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, user-interface

So here's my issue: I'm creating a pretty simple user input form, except some fields are not always relevant. For example, if the user is adding a staff member who is temporary, the user needs to enter an expiration date (date staff member leaves). Otherwise, if the staff member is regular, it is not logical to have that field present. Or the field could be present, and just "ghosted" (not sure if that's an actual term). The thing is... I know absolutely no jquery or javascript! If anyone has a solution to this problem, would they mind posting a template/example that I could follow? That would help me out very much! If not, any hints as to how to do in PHP/html (if possible) would be good too. I really appreciate any suggestions, thanks :-)

Comment: Your "ghosting" is done by adding the `disabled="disabled"` attribute to any `<input>` tag. As for an answer: it would be fruitless for us to provide you with any JavaScript/jQuery solutions if you have no familiarity with the language.

Comment: Show some relevant code and please use paragraphs.

Comment: @Blazemonger yes - thank you! that is exactly what I needed. And I know, I just didn't know it was possible to do in html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `onchange` to the field that determines if another field is going to be disabled.

Example:

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById('otherField').disabled=(this.value == 0)">
    <option value=1>Enable other field</option>
    <option value=0>Disable other field</option>
</select>

<input id='otherField' />​​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xB8CP/

Comment: That's great, thank you! Do you know if it's possible to have something already present in the text box - like "Enter expiration date here"?

Comment: Sounds like you want a placeholder. There is a new attribute in HTML5 called placeholder, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder . Although, it is usually better to use a `<label>` tag if possible as not all browsers support placeholder. It is also possible to use javascript to simulate placeholder: http://widgetulous.com/placeholderjs/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, but it wasn't quite what I was looking for. I did a bit of Google-ing on my own and came up with a straightforward piece of code.

So, here's a simple solution for people who don't know Javascript but want to create this effect:

The first bit was contributed by Jcubed (see below). It creates a simple drop down menu that "locks" the textbox based on what the user inputs

```
</td> <td><select name="employee_type" onchange="document.getElementById('otherField').disabled=(this.value == 0)">
<option value=1>Option 1</option>
<option value=0>Option 2</option>
```

The last bit is the part that creates the opaque letters that fade away when the user clicks on the textbox:

```
<input id="otherField" type="text" name="date_expires" value="What you want to appear in the text..." style="color:#aaa; font-style:italic;" onclick="this.value=''; this.style.color='#000'; this.style.fontStyle='normal';" />
```